# How to add a jar for Groovy plugin in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I need to use some classes in httpclient.jar when building a project in Jenkins. I added this jar to both {Groovy_Classpath}\lib and {Jenkins_Path}\plugins\groovy\WEB-INF\lib and tried to imported into my job (also see the screenshot below):

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.*
import groovy.*
import org.apache.http.*

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
```

[image]

It has two issues:

```
startup failed: 
Script1.groovy: 6: unable to resolve class HttpClient 
@ line 6, column 12. 
   HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build(); 
              ^ 
1 error
```

So I removed HttpClient and saw another:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: HttpClientBuilder for class: xxxx
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: HttpClientBuilder
```

I guess probably they meant the same thing - the class couldn't be found. But I have no idea how to resolve as I've added the jar to classpath...

Updated on the basis of Mike W's suggesion
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the dependency using Grape, add the following to the top of your script.

```
@Grab(group='org.apache.httpcomponents', module='httpclient', version='4.5.3'))
```

Comment: It has this error:Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6!commons-codec.jar]. I should also add that commons-codec.jar too?

Comment: commons-codec is a dependency of httpclient which should be pulled down with httpclient, there seems to be an issue when trying to download it, change the version of httpclient to 4.5.3 which should pull in commons-code version 1.9 which I've tried locally successfully

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've updated the statement with 4.5.3, but still have the error in the screenshot...

Comment: Have the dependencies been pulled into ~/.groovy/grapes ?

Comment: Seems no. I added a screenshot of the directory. Even the httpclient was added by me manually

Comment: The jars will be in the <user_home>/.groovy/grapes directory

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your reply last week. I was on vacation so didn't have internet access then. It seems something is still wrong as it shows "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ivy/core/settings/IvySettings" now. But I've reported to my boss and we decided to go the other way. So thanks for your kind suggestion :)